# узнать знак, порядок, мантиссу float без доп. модулей

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код с модулем `struct`

```
import struct

f = float(input())
d = struct.pack('d', f)
Q = struct.unpack('Q', d)[0]
bs = format(Q, '064b')
print(bs)
sign = bs[0]
print('Знак:', sign)
exponent = int(bs[1:12], 2) - 1023
print('Порядок:', exponent, '')
fraction = bs[12:]
print('Мантисса:', fraction)
r = 2**exponent + sum(int(b) * 2**(exponent - i - 1) for i, b in enumerate(fraction))
```

Как узнать знак, порядок, мантиссу float для одинарной и двойной точности не используя struct?

Comment: Например, делите на 2, пока `abs(x) >= 2`, увеличивая порядок, умножайте на 2, пока `abs(x) < 1`, уменьшая порядок. Или поиграйте с `x.as_integer_ratio()`. Аккуратно отнеситесь к денормализованным числам, нулю, NaN и бесконечностям. Оно вам правда надо без struct?

Comment: Просто было интересно, каким образом можно было это сделать не используя ничего дополнительного.